# C#/C++ application for remote Login on Desktop like Remote Desktop does

Tags: c#, c++, remote-desktop, teamviewer, desktop-duplication

I'm creating c#/c++ app for Windows, that functions like Remote Desktop.
Screen capturing is done with Desktop Duplication Api. Network transfer use TCP. And everything works fine. No technical issues.

I'm asking for the way to do Login function like Remote Desktop does. When user connect with Remote Desktop, locally computer is locked. Complete desktop is transferred over network, while locally computer is locked. What is the way to achieve this behavior of system.

I checked TeamViewer and AnyDesk. No one of these softwares have a such function. They just stream desktop to remote point computer. Meanwhile computer locally is not locked.

Thanks

Comment: Remote desktop completely takes over the session and disconnects it from the console. You probably just want to reuse that infrastructure. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/remote-desktop-activex-control

Comment: Have you heard about open source rustdesk, it's written in Rust though